# Jboss logger validation

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

How can I configure logger in standalone.xml for write messages only for one class or package?

For example:

```
17:56:41 ERROR [com.google.test] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) Test message Google 
17:56:41 ERROR [com.yaahoo.test] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) Test message Yaahoo
```

I want to select messages only for class com.google.test

My handler doesn't work

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
                <filter-spec value="any(match(&quot;[com.google.test]*&quot;))"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="Error.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
 </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the file handler but you haven't defined the logger, have you? You should add your logger in the standalone xml:

```
<logger category="com.google.test" use-parent-handlers="false">
   <level name="ERROR"/>
   <handlers>
       <handler name="FILE"/>
   </handlers>
</logger>
```

Also check the official [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Logging+Configuration?_sscc=t)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a `<logger>` section to that configuration

such as

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <logger category="com.google.test">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
```